# is my dbus setup broken? (or: why aren't the envvars set?)

Tags: gentoo, dbus

Lots of dbus-using applications respond to method calls and send signals just fine, so obviously not everything is broken for me. However:

1. In my terminals, $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_FOO environment variables are never set automatically; I have to either run `eval $(dbus-launch)` or `eval` the contents of `~/.dbus/session-bus/[machine-id]`. This also affects *some* but not all programmatic interfaces to dbus—python-dbus can connect to the session bus just fine, but dbus-core running under Haskell needs to set up the environment variables for itself.
2. Some applications do *not* work right; e.g., audacious doesn't send signals (running it with `--verbose` reveals that it gets passed  `NULL` instead of a proxy).

I've tried launching fluxbox using dbus-launch, as suggested in dbus-launch's man page, but that doesn't affect anything. Is there some simple config thing missing?

Comment: Is this still valid? Also, are you using any display manager? Please consider reporting this to Gentoo Bugzilla; fluxbox maintainers may be able to actually help you.